# Inserting a clone in to a list?

Tags: jquery

I have a ul with several li's.

I insert a clone of an element after the last li.

The problem is, the user can delete all li's leaving an empty list, then when I go to insert a  clone I cannot target the list properly.

```
$(myClone).clone(true).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('ul.myList li:last'));
```

The above works for when there is elements in the list, I need something taht works for when there is something in the list and when there isnt.

Comment: can you post some `HTML` for above query? Why don't check if there exists a `li', if there isn't you can change it to `$(myClone).clone(true).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('ul.myList '));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
$(this).parent().find('ul.myList').append($(myClone).clone(true));
```